# Place text on a picture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, imageresizer

I wonder if there's an easy and clean solution to put a text on a picture non-destructively.

For example: I have a picture I can call:

```
http://localhost:7001/Content/img/defaultPicutre.png
```

Having a default text on the picture I could call it this way:

```
http://localhost:7001/Content/img/defaultPicutre.png?text=Default%20Text
```

I know this is possible with resizing images with http://imageresizing.net/.
But I'm not sure if they provide the functionality I'd like to have.

Do they or are there any alternatives?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, imageresizer doesn't do that.You can try using GDI+

Comment: I basically don't want to change my "default picture" and either don't want to save a new picture with the text on it ... :(

Comment: You can do it in the memorystream and write it back to the response stream

Comment: @cherhan Performance and scalability might be important to him. ImageResizer offers both, and has offered text overlay functionality since 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ImageResizer allows you to do *exactly* that with the [Watermark plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/watermark).

Example Web.config segment

```
<resizer>
  <watermarks>
    <text name="custom" text="Hello #{text}!" align="topright" />
  </watermarks>
</resizer>
```

Example URL

```
http://localhost/Content/img/picture.png?text=Default%20Text&watermark=custom
```

The Watermark plugin (which would be better named the Overlays plugin) gives you tremendous layout flexibility, supports image and text layers, and supports pre-processing of image layers.

The [full configuration reference can be found here](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/watermark).